# How would you make a header that does a file reading function in c++

Tags: c++, file, io

This may sound newbie but, I am trying to make an external header that does a function that is reading from a file a name like joey and saving it as a variable to the other code it read from but i cant figure it out...It will be like this...One code will get this name and it will write it to the file...Then i want to use this header to read this file without writing the full code again but i cant seem to find a way to save the name read to a variable..

Comment: So you have working code right now, but want to move some of it to another file using a header file?

Comment: No, I cannot get this part of code to work that will read from the file and send it to another header in the program idk if it will have to use pointers, I havent learned pointers yet.

Comment: You want to make a function that reads a name from a textfile and saves that name into a variable which is returned by this function?
And you want to put the declaration of this function in a header (*.h) file? I can't follow your text :\

Comment: I will try to explain better my explaining sucks...So i have a code that gets a username from a user for registering and then it saves that to a file called name.dat, Then I want to make a header file like namereader.h that will have a code like void nameread() that will read that name from the file name.dat whenever i include it into the source code...But it still says variable undeclared when i try to compile...Like i will have the function nameread(); in my code and then i put cout<<name<<endl; but it will say name undeclared first us...But i declare it in the header as the variable name;

Comment: could you post the code you have

Comment: posted code here

http://rafb.net/p/eqcM1I15.html

Comment: That code is missing "rname.h" and "Create New.h". Also, please just edit your post and put the code right in there, it's more noticable that way (and gives your question a nice bump)

Comment: Also, please use indentation. It's very, very hard to read that code without proper indenting.

Answer (score 1):

All right, this isn't very clear.  Can you lay out something like pseudocode to explain it?

If I'm at all understanding you, you want to write data to a file in one place, and read it from other places, and you want the code to read it to be in a header fle.  There's nothing particularly impossible about this, but there are lots of easier better ways to handle it.